# The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient' is either not registered in the machine or application config file

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Tenho um projeto em MVC, e queria conectar ao banco MySql.
Eu coloquei essa `connectionStrings`.

```xml
<add name="Contexto" connectionString="server=127.0.0.1;User Id=xxxxxx;password=xxxxx;database=iesb_site" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
```

mas toda vez vou fazer o `Update-Migrations` aparece o seguinte erro:

> The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient' is either not registered in the machine or application config file, or could not be loaded. See the inner exception for details.

Comment: Conseguiu resolver o problema? Precisa que algo seja melhorado na resposta?

Answer (score 10):

Pra fazer o Entity Framework funcionar com o MySQL não é tão simples como com o SQL Server.

Antes é necessário fazer algumas configurações.

1. Instalar o pacote **MySql.Data.Entity.EF6**

   > Install-Package MySql.Data.Entity.EF6
2. Editar a seção **`<entityFramework>`** no arquivo *web.config*  (ou *app.config*) e adicionar o provider `MySql.Data` (linha 4 do exemplo - substituir toda a seção por esta abaixo também deve funcionar)

   ```xml
   <entityFramework>
     <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework"/>
     <providers>
       <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" 
                 type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6"/>
       <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
                 type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
     </providers>
   </entityFramework>
   ```
3. Setar uma nova classe `DbConfiguration` para o MySQL. Isso pode ser feito de três formas:

   3.1. Adicionar o atributo `DbConfigurationType` na classe de contexto atual

   ```
   [DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySqlEFConfiguration))]
   public class MeuContexto: DbContext { }
   ```

   3.2. Chamar `DbConfiguration.SetConfiguration(new MySqlEFConfiguration())` sempre que aplicação for inicializada. Por exemplo, numa aplicação ASP.NET MVC, este código pode ser colocado no método `Application_Start` do arquivo Global.asax.

   3.3. Referenciar a classe `MySqlEFConfiguration` no arquivo *web.config*

   ```
   <entityFramework codeConfigurationType="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6">
   ```

Comment: Muito bom, funcionou para mim perfeitamente.