# Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor

Tags: c#, .net

Estou recebendo esse ***erro*** após dar `deploy(AWS)` da minha `WebApi`.

***Nota:*** *LOCAL FUNCIONA PERFEITAMENTE*.

> `<ExceptionMessage>
>     An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 
>     'LivroController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public 
>      constructor.
>   </ExceptionMessage>`

Meu `controller`:

```
public class LivroController : BaseODataController<Livro>
{
  public LivroController() : base()
    {}
}
```

Meu Base `OdataController`:

```
public class BaseODataController<TEntity> : ODataController, 
IBaseController<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    private readonly IRepositoryBase<TEntity> Repository;

    public BaseODataController()
    {
        Repository = new RepositoryBase<TEntity>();
    }

    [EnableQuery]
    public IList<TEntity> Get()
    {
        return Repository.Get().ToList();
    }
}
```

já coloquei um construtor vazio em `LivroController`, porem que continua com o mesmo ***erro***.

Imagem com erro completo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Já comparou se as versões .net local e na AWS estão idênticas?

Comment: sim, fiz os testes local e eu mesmo subi.

Comment: Funciona perfeitamente publicado localmente? Ou funciona perfeitamente em DEBUG?

Comment: funciona perfeitamente quando estou debugando, quando mando para o servidor acontece o erro

Comment: Tenta fazer um construtor para LivroController chamando o base: `public LivroController() : base () {}`

Comment: não funcionou @GabrielColetta, tambem editei a pergunta com o construtor, e inclui uma imagem com todo o erro.

Comment: @Vinicius Leia **sempre** a _inner exception_ mais interna existente. Veja que o erro diz: "_The provider for invariant name MySql.Data.MySqlClient is specified multiple times_ [...]"

Comment: @LINQ obrigado pela dica e pela resposta [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/185683/8802)